# Android Doesn't Have Enough Tiles for Page?

Tags: android

When I open my activity the screen is just blank...then I see the above error in the log:

`01-28 15:19:03.000: D/TiledPage(3366): ERROR: We don't have enough tiles for this page! nbTilesHeight 427575 nbTilesWidth 786344`

I am lost as to where I need to go from here.  The application has worked fine in the past, now it is just showing a blank screen.

The layout for the activity being displayed is the actionbar and a webview filling the remaining space.  Not even the actionbar is appearing, so, I don't think it has to do with the webview specifically.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**Update:**

When I force close the app, and open it again, it works.  Obviously, I don't want this to happen when a user is using the application, so, what can I do to prevent it in the future?  It would help to know how to find the actual cause.

Answer (score 4):

Do you have hardware acceleration turned on?
You can try turning it off by setting `View.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);`.
This turns off the hardware acceleration just for the view. You can also turn it globally.
Check [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html) for more information on Hardware Acceleration.